# Unable to search for record in couchbase using java

Tags: java, couchbase

I am unable to get data out of this search.

**JSON**

```js
{
  "tenantId": "5",
  "featureId": "3",
  "data": "helloooooo",
  "companyCode": "ggsl8233"
}
```

**Java code**

```java
SearchResult searchResult = cluster.searchQuery(
               "idx_comcode", 
               SearchQuery.queryString("[{\"companyCode\":\"gg8233\",\"tenantId\":\"3\",\"featureId\":\"5\"}]"));

System.out.println(searchResult);
    
for (SearchRow row : searchResult.rows()) {              
     System.out.println("Document Id: " + row.id());
}
```

I am not getting any error but at the same time no data is displayed.

Comment: For single field i am getting data but for this, no data is displayed

Comment: Could you please post how you built `idx_comcode`?